# Congruence equation of 2 unknown numbers

Tags: congruences, gcd-and-lcm

I can't figure out how to solve the: $$s'*51+t'*39=gcd(51,39)$$

I solved:

$$s'*51+t'*39=gcd(51,39) \to 3=-3*51+4*39$$

Are there any couples of whole numbers $(s',t')$ that solves my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use that $gcd(51,39)=3$

Comment: You know basic theory of Diophantine equations?

Comment: If ax+ by= c, has integer solution x= x0 and y= y0 then x= x0+ bk,  y= y0- ak is also an integer solution for any integer k:  a(x0+ bk)+ b(y0- ak)= ax0+ abk+ by0- abk= ax0+ by0= c.

Comment: @user247327 Not sure what you mean, do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

2x+ 3y= 7 has x= 2, y= 1 as solution.  It also has x= 2+ 3k, y= 1- 2k as solutions, for k any integer.  As I showed before, 2(2+ 3k)+ 3(1- 2k)= 4+ 6k+ 3- 6k= 7.  Taking k= 1, x= 5, y= -1 is a solution: 2(5)+ 3(-1)= 10- 3= 7.  Taking k= 2, x= 8, y= -3 is a solution: 2(8)+ 3(-3)= 16- 9= 7.  Taking k= -1, x= -1, y= 3 is a solution: 2(-1)+ 3(3)= -2+ 9= 7.